Remove specific decimal from integer
Let's say we have value 2006 and now I want to remove 0 from it and the result is 26.
Value : 2006
After removing 0, the value is : 26
I have tried to replace directly using replace but in some case like using aggregate functions we can not use it directly.

I have added this question for knowledge. May be some of you guys already know about it. If any of us know well better, than this answer then please add it bellow.
you can also add your answer for MySQL, Oracle.
Thanks.

The question as it currently stands is useless and much too vague. "Some case", "like", "we can't", no one can work with such vague statements. Please ask a clear, concrete question or delete yours again.

Example where the replace is used with a grouping function
CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    ID  Int,
    Result  Varchar(4)
);

INSERT INTO Example (ID,Result) VALUES
    (1,'2006'),
    (1,'2007'),
    (1,'2008'),
    (2,'2009'),
    (2,'2010');


SELECT ID, 
       MAX(Result) as maxresult, 
       MAX(REPLACE(Result,'0','')) as MaxResultWithoutZeros 
FROM Example
GROUP BY ID

fiddle



ID
maxresult
MaxResultWithoutZeros




1
2008
28


2
2010
29




Thank you for giving broad view for understanding it is better.

For Microsoft SQL Server
SELECT CONVERT(integer, REPLACE(2006,'0', ''));

